# Add an array elements into PHP/ Insert variable with value with Array_push

Tags: php, json, youtube, gdata

I am able to parse data from youtube gdata. For example:

```
$json_output = json_decode($json,TRUE);
foreach ( $json_output['data']['items'] as $data ){

echo $data['content'][1]
. '</br>' 
. $data['title'];
```

These give me rtsp url and title. Now suppose I want some other elements to add to the output (I don't possess knowledge of php, so I don't know the terms actually). What I want, that the output should have an another variable, let's take 'Boys'. This variable will have index key values same as youtube gdata and will be as follows:
Boys="You", "Me", "He", "Doggy",.....nth value.
My above code gives two values each time-url and title. Now I want the 3rd value which will be added to that from 'Boys'.
I tried Array_push as follows but it adds as an extra element and not as a variable like 'title' or 'content'.

```
$Boys= array('demi', 'ffe', 'erere');
array_push($json_output['data']['items'], $Boys );
```

How to properly insert Boys as variable? is there other methods like merge etc. to do it?
Again, since I am not a coder, please pardon my words!

Comment: `array_merge` can be a good option instead of `array_push`.. try it..

Comment: Shaunak, can you help me with my question?

Comment: sure, try with `array_merge($json_output['data']['items'], $Boys );` is it giving proper?

Comment: I got your problem, but still unclear how you want to merge two arrays!

Comment: No, same result, added at last...I think 'Boys' here is not a variable type. It should be like a variable like 'title'.

Comment: ok then you can add it like `$json_output['data']['items']['Boys'] = $Boys`

Comment: It would be really helpful if you posted your desired result (what should the array look like afterwards?)

Comment: @ShaunakShukla, please see url: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=whatever&v=2&max-results=5&format=1&alt=jsonc.....I want to add element like title, content etc.

Comment: @Hirnhamster, Till my result is 'code' url,title and I want the result url,title, a name from 'Boys'

Comment: Till I get `url, title` and I want like `url, title, a name from 'Boys'`

Comment: @Hirnhamster `Best of whatever 2013
rtsp://r3---sn-o097zuee.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQmMKLazIS6kpRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
[---I want a name here---]
2 Girls Asking For 3somes
rtsp://r4---sn-o097zuek.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlmFTJbhKvUOhMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
[---I want a name here---]`

Comment: Thanks all for helping. But I think I was unable to convey what I wanted. I have opened a new question to describe the issue. Please see the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464896/how-to-add-key-values-into-decoded-json-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 2 arrays with same keys, then you can do array_merge_recursive() to merge them together.

Here is a working example,

```
$a = [ 'boys' => ['play', 'sing']];
$b = ['boys' => 'fight'];
$merged = array_merge_recursive($a, $b);
print_r($merged);
```

Comment: The keys are different. Please refer url:http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=whatever&v=2&max-results=5&format=1&alt=jsonc.........................I want to add an element like title, content, sqdefault etc.

Comment: Thanks all for helping. But I think I was unable to convey what I wanted. I have opened a new question to describe the issue. Please see the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464896/how-to-add-key-values-into-decoded-json-in-php