# How to add key values into decoded json in PHP?

Tags: php, json, youtube

I use youtube gdata to get video links. PHP code I use:

```
$json_output = json_decode($json,TRUE);
foreach ( $json_output['data']['items'] as $data ){

echo $data['title']
. '</br>' 
. $data['content'][1]
. '</br>';
```

The url is http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=whatever&v=2&max-results=5&format=1&alt=jsonc. This gives me the following output:

```
 Best of whatever 2013
rtsp://r3---sn-o097zuee.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQmMKLazIS6kpRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
2 Girls Asking For 3somes
rtsp://r4---sn-o097zuek.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlmFTJbhKvUOhMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
Girl Picking Up Girls
rtsp://r8---sn-o097zuer.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQk1tOjZuJyf2RMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
Awkward Track Situations
rtsp://r8---sn-o097zuek.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQkYo23fr3XTdRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
Asking 200 Girls For Sex (Social Experiment)
rtsp://r8---sn-o097zued.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlzWxK8A722IhMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
```

Now I want something like below:

```
Best of whatever 2013
rtsp://r3---sn-o097zuee.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQmMKLazIS6kpRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
[---I want a name here---]
2 Girls Asking For 3somes
rtsp://r4---sn-o097zuek.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlmFTJbhKvUOhMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
[---I want a name here---]
Girl Picking Up Girls
rtsp://r8---sn-o097zuer.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQk1tOjZuJyf2RMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
[---I want a name here---]
Awkward Track Situations
rtsp://r8---sn-o097zuek.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQkYo23fr3XTdRMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
[---I want a name here---]
Asking 200 Girls For Sex (Social Experiment)
rtsp://r8---sn-o097zued.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlzWxK8A722IhMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
[---I want a name here---]
```

The names are indexed array like:

```
Names=Red, Green, You, Me.....
```

How to perform this? I used array_push or merge functions, but it adds only an array, not a variable like Title or Content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a counter outside the `foreach` like `$count = 0;` then inside the `foreach` do `$count++;`. You can then get the name corresponding to the item using `$names[$count];` inside the `foreach`.

```
$json_output = json_decode($json,TRUE);
$count = 0;
$names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4'];
foreach ( $json_output['data']['items'] as $data ){
     echo ($data['title'] . '<br />' . $data['content'][1] . '<br />' . $names[$count] . '<br />');
     $count++;
}
```

Comment: I am not well with php. Can you give me idea how I do in ref to above situation? @Ali

Comment: @IndiApp I updated my answer. (I have not actually looked at the resulting JSON from YouTube's API so I'm just assuming your code was working like you said.)

Comment: Very useful and almost got the result. But for 4th and 5th object got the following error: `Notice: Undefined offset: 4 Notice: Undefined offset: 5`

Comment: @IndiApp Did you add the same number of items into the `$names` array as you have results? I just put 4 but I don't know how many you have. (Also, I updated the code, please try again.)

Comment: Interesting, I just copied and pasted!!! Now, if I add two more names then the error goes like :`$names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5', 'name6'];`....what is logic behind it?...Oh sorry, the names does not show after 3rd

Comment: @IndiApp All the code does is increment a counter, `$count`, for each result then display the string at that index from the `$names` array. If you have more results than you have names, you are trying to get an item that doesn't exist in that array. For example, `$names[100]` would give you an warning until you have 101 items in the array. (Indexes start at 0).

Comment: Got your point...I don't know if other ways are there or not. But it accomplishes my need. So, VERY much thanks for you! You solved the issue at once!